# Giving full access / permission / control for a program on WIN8

Tags: windows, windows-8, permissions

There are three parties involved here.

I used a program to lock some folders on my PC of win8 and new issues occured.

I have a program that usually syncs one of the folders in that same directory. It no longer works because it is getting the access denied message.

But the Antivirus (AVG) can scan the folders without any issues.

So I want to give the program the same level of permission that AVG has so that it works when the security is on.

Comment: Run the program as an Administrator

Comment: I just tried and did not work.